# Android SDK Get where clicked on image

Tags: android

I've an `ImageView`, but how can I see where the user has *clicked/touched* on the image.

I know I have to use `MotionEvent.getX()` and `MotionEvent.getY()`, but how can I see where the user has clicked on the image?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to subclass your image view and explicitly draw an indicator at the position where the user is touching.

```
public class TouchableImageView extends ImageView {

  // Constructors should come here

  // Override onTouch to remember the touch position in our variable touchLocation
  // Set touchLocation to null when getting the ACTION_UP event

  // Override onDraw to draw something at touchLocation. You should create a proper Paint object
  // in your constructors and use it here
  public void onDraw(Canvas c) {
    if (touchLocation!=null) {
      canvas.drawCircle(touchLocation.x, touchLocation.y, 10, indicatorPaint);
    }
  }

  private Point touchLocation;
  private Paint indicatorPaint;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's pretty helpfull!

Comment: Yeah I know, but I have to wait 3 minutes. Haha